# C++ Boost Library - Minimum cost maximum flow

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to piece together this [example](http://www.programmingexamples.net/wiki/CPP/Boost/BGL/DijkstraDirected) with this [sample](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/graph/example/cycle_canceling_example.cpp). I got this to compile and run:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/push_relabel_max_flow.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/edmonds_karp_max_flow.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/cycle_canceling.hpp> 

using namespace boost;

typedef int EdgeWeightType;

typedef adjacency_list_traits < vecS, vecS, directedS > Traits;
typedef adjacency_list < vecS, vecS, directedS,
  property < vertex_name_t, std::string,
    property < vertex_index_t, long,
      property < vertex_color_t, boost::default_color_type,
        property < vertex_distance_t, long,
          property < vertex_predecessor_t, Traits::edge_descriptor > > > > >,

  property < edge_capacity_t, EdgeWeightType,
    property < edge_weight_t, EdgeWeightType,
        property < edge_residual_capacity_t, EdgeWeightType,
            property < edge_reverse_t, Traits::edge_descriptor > > > > > Graph;

Traits::edge_descriptor AddEdge(Traits::vertex_descriptor &v1,
                                Traits::vertex_descriptor &v2,
                                property_map < Graph, edge_reverse_t >::type &rev,
                                const double capacity,
                                const double weight, 
                                Graph &g);

int main(int, char*[])
{
  Graph g; //a graph with 0 vertices

  property_map < Graph, edge_reverse_t >::type rev = get(edge_reverse, g);

  //add a source and sink node, and store them in s and t, respectively
  Traits::vertex_descriptor v0 = add_vertex(g);
  Traits::vertex_descriptor v1 = add_vertex(g);
  Traits::vertex_descriptor v2 = add_vertex(g);
  Traits::vertex_descriptor v3 = add_vertex(g);

  Traits::vertex_descriptor v4 = add_vertex(g);
  Traits::vertex_descriptor v5 = add_vertex(g);
  Traits::vertex_descriptor v6 = add_vertex(g);
  Traits::vertex_descriptor v7 = add_vertex(g);
  Traits::vertex_descriptor v8 = add_vertex(g);
  Traits::vertex_descriptor v9 = add_vertex(g);
  Traits::vertex_descriptor v10 = add_vertex(g);
  Traits::vertex_descriptor v11 = add_vertex(g);

  AddEdge(v0, v1, rev, 1, 1, g);
  AddEdge(v0, v2, rev, 1, 1, g);
  AddEdge(v0, v3, rev, 1, 1, g);

  AddEdge(v1, v4, rev, 100, 10, g);
  AddEdge(v1, v5, rev, 100, 2, g);

  AddEdge(v2, v6, rev, 100, 10, g);
  AddEdge(v2, v7, rev, 100, 2, g);

  AddEdge(v3, v8, rev, 100, 10, g);
  AddEdge(v3, v9, rev, 100, 2, g);

  AddEdge(v4, v11, rev, 100, 1, g);
  AddEdge(v6, v11, rev, 100, 1, g);
  AddEdge(v8, v11, rev, 100, 1, g);

  AddEdge(v5, v10, rev, 100, 1, g);
  AddEdge(v7, v10, rev, 100, 1, g);
  AddEdge(v9, v10, rev, 100, 1, g);  

  AddEdge(v10, v11, rev, 100, 1, g);


  //find min cut
  //EdgeWeightType flow = boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow(g, v0, v3); // a list of sources will be returned in s, and a list of sinks will be returned in t
  //EdgeWeightType flow = push_relabel_max_flow(g, v0, v3); // a list of sources will be returned in s, and a list of sinks will be returned in t
  EdgeWeightType flow = edmonds_karp_max_flow(g, v0, v11); // a list of sources will be returned in s, and a list of sinks will be returned in t
  boost::cycle_canceling(g);

  int cost = boost::find_flow_cost(g);

  std::cout << "Flow cost is " << cost << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Max flow is: " << flow << std::endl;

  property_map<Graph, edge_capacity_t>::type
          capacity = get(edge_capacity, g);
  property_map<Graph, edge_residual_capacity_t>::type
          residual_capacity = get(edge_residual_capacity, g);


  graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_iterator u_iter, u_end;
  graph_traits<Graph>::out_edge_iterator ei, e_end;
  for (tie(u_iter, u_end) = vertices(g); u_iter != u_end; ++u_iter)
      for (tie(ei, e_end) = out_edges(*u_iter, g); ei != e_end; ++ei)
          if (capacity[*ei] > 0)
              std::cout << "Source: " << *u_iter << " destination: " << target(*ei, g) << " capacity: "  << capacity[*ei] << "residual cap: " << residual_capacity[*ei] << " used capacity: "
                      << (capacity[*ei] - residual_capacity[*ei]) << std::endl;

 return 0;
}

Traits::edge_descriptor AddEdge(Traits::vertex_descriptor &v1, Traits::vertex_descriptor &v2, property_map < Graph, edge_reverse_t >::type &rev, const double capacity, const double weight, Graph &g)
{
  Traits::edge_descriptor e1 = add_edge(v1, v2, g).first;
  Traits::edge_descriptor e2 = add_edge(v2, v1, g).first;
  put(edge_capacity, g, e1, capacity);
  put(edge_capacity, g, e2, capacity);
  put(edge_weight, g, e1, weight);
  put(edge_weight, g, e2, weight);
  rev[e1] = e2;
  rev[e2] = e1;
}
```

I expect that the minimum cost maximum flow should pick the edges from v1 to v5, v2 to v7 and v3 to v9, as these edges have lower costs compared to edges v1 to v4, v2 to v6 and v3 to v8. However, that is not what results when I run the program.

Can you please point out what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks and best regards
Muhammad Saqib Ilyas

Answer (score 0):

I located the min_cost_max_flow_utils.hpp file in libs\graph\test. I modified the getSampleGraph() function to create my own graph and solved it successfully.